# Drop table sqlite issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

I've been able to drop and reload tables using this same code structure, but running into an issue for this table. Essentially what my code intends to do is allow the user to delete their custom selections and restore defaults.  Any insight on why I'm unable to drop table is appreciated.

EDIT:  the issue was that the inital table to drop did not exist.  I ended up using sqlite3_errmsg to figure that out.

```
 - (void) dropReloadFoodlistTable{
const char *dbpath = [_databasePath UTF8String];
sqlite3_stmt    *statement;

if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &_profileDB) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    NSString *querySQL = @"DROP TABLE FOODLIST";

    const char *query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];

    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(_profileDB,
                           query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
        {
            NSLog(@"SQL Statement complete");
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    }

    char *errMsg2;
    const char *sql_stmt2 =
    "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS FOODLIST (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, CARB STRING, PROTEIN STRING, FAT STRING, FRUIT STRING, VEG STRING)";

    if (sqlite3_exec(_profileDB, sql_stmt2, NULL, NULL, &errMsg2) != SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSLog( @"Failed to create FOODLIST table");
    }


    sqlite3_close(_profileDB);
}


[self initialDataLoadFoodList];

}
```

Comment: Where does the code fail? Use `sqlite3_errmsg` to find out the error.

Comment: It would also help if you actually performed the `DROP` statement. All you do is prepare a statement and then finalize it.

Comment: -1.  Failed to describe the error, failed to make use of sqlite3_errmsg.

Comment: the issue was that the inital table to drop did not exist.  I ended up using sqlite3_errmsg to figure that out.

Comment: Please rewrite your edit as an answer. It's fine to answer your own question, but you should do it in an actual answer, not as an edit to the question.

Answer (score 0):

This code does not execute the `DROP TABLE` statement.

To execute a prepared statement, you must call [sqlite3_step](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/step.html).

Answer (score 0):

You prepare the statement, but never use `sqlite3_step()` to actually execute it.

([reference](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/prepare.html))

Comment: I edited the code, but the problem is it doesn't get past the prepare to actually run the step

Comment: `DROP` statements need to be run with `sqlite3_exec`, just like your `CREATE` statement.

Comment: the issue was that the inital table to drop did not exist.  I ended up using sqlite3_errmsg to figure that out.